# MySQL - load data infile - how to read and insert line number into table?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, load-data-infile

I am using MySQL's LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE feature to load lines of record from text file into table. Everything works fine but I am wondering how can I insert line number from the text file into LINE_NUMBER column of my table?

```
public String getLoadDataSQL() throws Exception {

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append( "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '"+ filePath +"' INTO TABLE "+ this.tableName );
    sb.append( " LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");
    sb.append( " (@line) ");
    sb.append( " SET ROLL_NUMBER = substr(@line,1,9),  ");
    sb.append( " LAST_NAME = substr(@line,10,30),  ");
    ....
    sb.append( " LINE_NUMBER = "+ ????? +",  "); // WHAT TO DO HERE??
    ...
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Could you please suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure if you can do that directly when you are loading data from a file. One hack would be to keep your `LINE_NUMBER` as an [`AUTO_INCREMENT` column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried but it seems the AUTO_INCREMENT logic isn't suitable for my problem.

Comment: @gt_ebuddy Can you do the import first into a temporary table with an AUTO_INCREMENT column, then copy that data into its final destination? Then you can have the line number always start with 1 and not worry about AUTO_INCREMENT's logic interfering. That approach was working for me until my hosting company told me I couldn't use temporary tables, which is how I got here searching for a different answer to our problem.